# How can i execute a php query from an html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I know php is a server-side language and html a client-side language and to do this i would use javascript but i don't know how to do.
Can someone help me to write the script called **changeFunction()**?

**This is my form in index.php:**

```
<form method="POST">
            <div class="row"style="margin-top: 5%;">
                <div class="col-3">

                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                   <label for="inputUsername">Insert username</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputUser" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
                   <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Convert account type to: </label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="inputSelected">
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                      <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                      <option value="user">User</option>
                    </select>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="changeFunction()">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**This is my query in query.php:**

```
 <?php     
 $var1= $_POST["inputGroupSelect01"];
 $var2= $_POST["inputUser"];
 require 'connection.php';
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET typeAcc =".$var1." WHERE username=".$var2;
 ?>
```

Comment: The [manual is here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Please know that SO is not a tutorial service

Comment: You don't need JavaScript. Add the PHP page as its action.  Submit the form. Then you can use the variables in $_POST. http://de2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the solution you want .

**First** add the following div in you html form `<div id='resultDiv' ></div>`

so your html form code be like this

```
<form method="POST" >
        <div class="row"style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <div class="col-3">
                <h2>Testing Form</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
               <label for="inputUsername">Insert username</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputUser" style="margin-bottom: 2%" id="inputUser">
               <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Convert account type to: </label>
                </div>
                <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="inputSelected">
                  <option selected>Choose...</option>
                  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                  <option value="user">User</option>
                </select>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="changeFunction()">Submit</button>
              </div>
              <!-- this need to be added -->
              <div id='resultDiv' ></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Second**  add the jQuery and following script to your code

two jquery variable define `userName` and `role` which is later passed as `data` 
and if server response is `SUCCESS` then success condition executed or you can send data or particular error message by setting `ERROR` with `YOUR ERROR TEXT`

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>

           function changeFunction(){
          var userName = $('#inputUser').val();
          var role     =$('#inputGroupSelect01').val();

         $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "server.php",
           data: JSON.stringify( { "userId": userName, "userRole": role } ),
           dataType: "text",

           success: function (response){
               if(response=='SUCCESS'){
                  $('#resultDiv').append('<br/>Successful Updated'+response);

            }else{
                $('#resultDiv').append('<br/>Error'+ response);
            }
        }

        });
      }
  </script>
```

**Third ** you have to write the new `server.php` file with following code

```
<?php     
    $var1= $_POST["userId"]; // change here userId as used in jquery block 
    $var2= $_POST["userRole"];// change here userRole as used in jquery  Block
     //require 'connection.php';
     $sql = "UPDATE user SET typeAcc =".$var1." WHERE username=".$var2;

    //suppose query is executed successfull then 
    //it will return no of rows updated


   $query_result = mysql_query($query);
   //SUCCESS_CONDITION is normally if number of row updated is 1 in return 
   ///of query execution so kindly define by your own way 

   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_result);
   //if($num_rows==1 || define your own SUCCESS_CONDITION){
   if($num_rows ==1){ 
     $result ='SUCCESS';
   }else{
      $result ='ERROR';
   }

  echo $result;
?>
```

I hope it will help 
Thanks 
Ask for help if needed

[image]

Comment: It works. I edited a small part of your PHP code because didn't work to me.

Comment: From here to end of php document: $query_result = mysql_query($query); I edited also the query:  $sql = 'UPDATE user SET typeAcc ="'.$var1.'" WHERE username="'.$var2'"';

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using PHP but you need to check $_POST data.

```
if(isset($_POST['inputGroupSelect01']) && isset($_POST['inputUser;]){
$var1= $_POST["inputGroupSelect01"];
 $var2= $_POST["inputUser"];
 require 'connection.php';
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET typeAcc =".$var1." WHERE username=".$var2;
}
```

By the way, that code is entirely vulnerable. You are taking 2 inputs from users and placing them directly, and placing them into a SQL query.

What if my input for var2 was `'; DROP TABLE user;` ?